Excel lookup with conditional logic
I find myself a little stuck and was hoping to get some help.
Note: the attached picture isn’t the actual data set I’m working with, just created a rough representation with made up entries to highlight the end goal.



Part
Operation no
Operation




Apple
Cut
10


Apple
Polish
20


Apple
Wash
30


Apple
Wax
40


Apple
Inspection
50


Orange
Pick
10


Orange
Soapy wash
20


Orange
Dry off
30


Orange
Inspection
40


Pineapple
Wash
10


Pineapple
Pack
20


Pineapple
Inspection
30


Lemon
Pick
10


Lemon
Wash
15


Lemon
Inspection
20


Lime
Pick
10


Lime
Soapy wash
20


Lime
Inspection
25



I am trying to extract a list of all parts that have either the wash operation or the soapy wash operation BUT I only want to grab cases where these are NOT the second last operation.
How do I go about doing this? I was thinking of somehow incorporating conditional logic in my lookups but somehow seem unable to have a working solution to execute.
Would love ideas from the community here! Thanks!
Edit: just realized my table didn’t copy over with formatting on my phone so adding an image
Edit2: The operation number column has numbers that determine relative position of that step (so op 10 will be performed before op 20 etc).
I am trying to extract a list of parts that have a specific operation (for example “wash”) performed anywhere except in second to last spot.
In the case of Apple, since wash is performed 3rd in a list of 5 operations (operation number 30 out of 50), I would want this to show up on my list but if I were trying to do the same logic based off the “soapy wash” operation, I would NOT want lime to be on my list.
https://imgur.com/a/HIjzW39
I tried using lookups with some of statements but lost my way and need help

I just want to exclude all cases where a part has a wash or a soapy was operation as the second to last step

=LET(parts, UNIQUE(FILTER(A:A,(--(B:B="Wash")+(B:B="Soapy wash"))>0)),
    penult, BYROW(parts,
        LAMBDA(x,
            INDEX(B:B,
                MATCH(1,
                    --(A:A=x)*--(C:C=MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,x,C:C,"<>"&MAXIFS(C:C,A:A,x))),
                    0
    )))),
    FILTER(parts,--(penult<>"Wash")*--(penult<>"Soapy wash")))


This will build 2 lists: the first list (parts) is the Unique List of parts that have "Wash" or "Soapy wash" as an operation.  The second list (penult) takes the first list, and gives you the corresponding Penultimate (second-to-last) operation.
Then we just filter parts, where penult is neither "Wash", nor "Soapy wash".
This will allow for multiple "Wash"/"Soapy wash" operations on a single part, no "Wash"/"Soapy wash" operations on a part, and "Wash"/"Soapy wash" being the last operation, etc

Not sure whether you are trying to achieve something like this or not:


=LET(
     _Data, A2:C19,
     _Part, TAKE(_Data,,1),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Part),
     _Output, DROP(REDUCE("", _Uniq, LAMBDA(x,y, 
     LET(z, FILTER(_Data, y=_Part,""), VSTACK(x, 
     TAKE(FILTER(z, ((INDEX(z,,2)="Wash")+(INDEX(z,,2)="Soapy wash"))*(SEQUENCE(ROWS(z),,ROWS(z),-1)<>2),""),,1))))),1),
     TOCOL(IFS(_Output<>"",_Output),2))


Or, use the following which is bit shorter and doesn't uses the recursive REDUCE() function:
=LET(
    _Parts, A2:A19,
    _Uniq, UNIQUE(_Parts),
    FILTER(_Uniq, MAP(_Uniq, LAMBDA(α, LET(δ, {"Wash","Soapy wash"},
    φ, FILTER(B2:B19,_Parts=α),OR(δ=φ)*(1-OR(LOOKUP("z",DROP(φ,-1))=δ)))))))



I’m trying to figure out a list of parts where wash or soapy wash do not happen in the second to last step

Thanks for the quick response! Would you know why I get a CALC! error when using this?

@MayukhBhattacharya Your version with the REDUCE will also exclude items where "Wash" or "Soapy wash" only appears as the last item, but your version without the REDUCE will include them — but also includes items without "Wash" or "Soapy wash" (Although, that's not actually one of the Test Cases in OP's data set… @Zuhair what should the correct output be in that case?)

There are no cases where wash or soapy wash is the last op!

@MayukhBhattacharya Unfortunately, this is a situation where the Test Cases don't quite match the Scope: the 2 examples I gave are ones that aren't in the given Test Cases, but are part of the "all parts that have either the wash operation or the soapy wash operation BUT I only want to grab cases where these are NOT the second last operation" question

@MayukhBhattacharya As said: add 2 more test cases of 3 operations each, (e.g. =TEXTSPLIT("Mango,Inspection,10;Mango,Pick,20;Mango,Wax,30;Papaya,Inspection,10;Papaya,Pick,20;Papaya,Wash,30",",",";")) that match the request scope, and the code gives the wrong output.  The Test Cases given are not exhaustive for all possibilities under the request, most notably explicitly ignoring the explicit "Only if the Part has 'Wash' or 'Soap Wash' as an Operation" condition.

@Chronocidal ok found it, will update it ! But the REDUCE() work correctly though, not the MAP() version

You can do it kind of dirty with a helper column and a Pivot Table:

Right know the Pivot Table returns all parts that got a Wash operation in a position diferent than second
Please, notice that this approach will work only if your data is sorted ans shown in image and with helper column.
Formula in helper column just add the operation number like first, second, third... for each part, with a numeric value. Formula is just =COUNTIF($A$2:A2,A2) (notice the reference is dinamic! $A$2:A2)
The create a Pivot Table and take field Part into rows section and take fields Helper and Operation No to filters section. Apply a filter to Helper to show everything except 2 to hide all second operations.
Then use the Operation No filter to get your desired output.
Another advantage of this approach is that you could probably create a table on your source data and then link the Pivot Table to it so it will update easily.

i like the use of helper columns with pivot as it is simpler for most basic to intermediate users. however, i want to exclude the second to last operations not the second and each part might have different number of operations. how would you suggest incorporating that into this solution?

@HAZ just to make sure I understand properly. You said i want to exclude the second to last operations, so that means you want actually only the first operation. Then  apply a filter to Helper to show only 1 to exclude all operations made in seconds steps or further.

This solution is based on each final step being Inspection:
=LET(o,B2:B19,
     r,TOCOL(ROW(o)/(o={"","Soapy "}&"Wash"),2),
INDEX(A:A,FILTER(r,INDEX(B:B,r+1)<>"Inspection")))

The range containing the Operation no is declared as o.
r gets you the row numbers of all rows containing Soapy Wash or Wash in o.
If we index column A with r+1 it should not contain Inspection it returns the the indexed column A with row r.

An attempt using tables and defining named functions (the functions could be part of LET if needed):
Table TableWash contains the data, and table OpsToLookup contains the input; by using tables you can easily add more data without changes the references in formulas.
Main function _is_second_to_last_op,
input: part and operation as array
=LAMBDA(part_op,  
LET(
filtered, FILTER(TableWash,(TableWash[Part]=TAKE(part_op,,1))),  
sorted, SORTBY(filtered, TAKE(filtered,,-1)),  
INDEX(sorted, ROWS(sorted) - 1, 2) = TAKE(part_op,,-1)))

For Results:
=LET(
filtered_parts_with_ops, FILTER(TableWash,COUNTIF(OpsToLookup,TableWash[Operation])), 
FILTER(filtered_parts_with_ops, NOT(BYROW(DROP(filtered_parts_with_ops,,-1), _is_second_to_last_op)))
)




With helper columns (sort the table first as shown):
Index within part: =COUNTIF(TableWash4[[#Headers],[Part]]:[@Part],[@Part])
Include:
=AND(
NOT((SUM(COUNTIF([Part],[@Part]))-[@[Index within Part]])=1),
COUNTIF(OpsToLookup5[Ops to lookup],[@Operation]))

Then results:
=FILTER(TableWash4[[Part]:[Operation no]],TableWash4[Include])


